# Tornado sockets using redis sub\pub

Tags: python, websocket, redis, tornado

I need advice about performance using web-sockets together with redis pub/sub channels. I use tornado as web-server.

I have about 100 clients which listen status of some event. Each client have separate event and need to listen only own event. Socket connection is short-live, something about 1-20 seconds. I see two options:

1. Create separate pub/sub channel in redis for each socket-event pair. In this case I will have many channels.
2. Create one pub/sub channel, subscribe all clients to it and filter messages in controller to forward them to appropriate client. In this case I have many clients which listen one channel.

Which of these options is better for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1)**

Assume you have `M` clients, each client subscribes to only one channel (and not subscribe to pattern), then the complexity for publishing `N` msg is `O(N)`.

**Case 2)**

Assume you have `M` clients subscribed to one channel, all the clients receive `N` messages. The publish and filtering process complexity is `O(MN)`.

So you should choose Case 1. Case 1 is faster because it is always constant time for redis to publish a message to a channel (unless it is a pattern)

Read about redis publish time complexity [here](http://redis.io/commands/publish)

Comment: A minor minor point on the matter of Big O. Both scenarios are O(N), in the sense they grow linearly. There is an obvious performance difference, but they are both still linear.